# Where do I submit XML to SOLR

Tags: java, post, solr

Been through the tutorials, it used a post.jar to submit the XMLs to SOLR.
Is it enough to `POST` the XML as string to `[solr-home]/update` ?

Answer (score 1):

For indexing normal data, its enough to have data as xml documents posted to Solr.
Solr would index each record as a document.

Solr also provides various indexing data options as indexing database using dataimport handlers, rich documents using extract handler, mail db files, rss feeds etc.

The process for indexing would vary depending upon the data you are indexing.

More info @
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html#Indexing+Data
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler